# OAuth Token Expiration Time increase Azure AD

Tags: azure

We are getting Access Token followed by Authorise token from Azure AD for Microsoft Graph Application which consist (SMTP, POP, IMAP, email and OpenID), this Access token is short live (60-90) mins, we got an article on MSDN to increase the token expiration time https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes, using this article we can generate policy but these policies are not applying on a token generated, as a requirement, we need long live Access Token (more than 3 months), let me know if there is any way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your case, but a common issue I have seen on this topic is that people normally apply the policy on the client service principal and not on the resource, which is wrong.

The accessToken is controlled by the resource Service Principal, which means that, to increase the lifetime of access tokens issued for MS Graph, you need to apply the policy to the MS Graph Service Principal.

I know this works when you set up your own custom API/resources, but not sure if it works for MS 1st party resources.

Nevertheless, you can make a test and target the MS Graph Service Principal, as below:

[image: MS Graph Service Principal]

To add on top of this, please note that, if the policy is applied successfully, it will change the lifetime of ALL the accessTokens issued for MS Graph, regardless of the client app. So do really think carefully if this is the behavior you would like/need to have.